# Changing un-orthogonal polygons to orthogonal ones in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, vector, geometry, editing

I am creating polygonal features in ArcGIS Pro 2.8.0 for a buildings layer of a site survey project. Working in a team, some of the polygons representing building footprints were not created with the benefit of using the "Right Angle Polygon" tool. If that had been used to begin with, the footprint-representing polygons would all be orthogonal (right angles in every corner).

Unfortunately, they are not.

[image: Trapezoidal Polygon (Before)]

Using the 'Edit Vertices' or 'Reshape' tools doesn't contain any parameters that I can find that offer the option of generating an orthogonal feature as an end result. The best offering from the documentation is at [this link](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/create-features-with-right-angles.htm), but it only refers to polygon *creation*, not *edits*.

[image: Orthogonal Polygon (desired state after)]

Am I missing an obvious method or technique to achieve the desired result as per my illustrations (upper image: before; lower image: desired state, after)? I find it hard to believe that there doesn't exist a means to accomplish this in the Edit menus or elsewhere.

Comment: This isn't a trivial task. You need to script a decision process that humans can evaluate with a glance. It will likely involve finding the *right-most* angle, shifting the "second" point to bend that to a full right angle, then moving the other two points to square it off. The edge cases are going to need review, though, since you can have some ugly ones.

Comment: Ah, thank you, Vince. I didn't grasp the depth of what I was asking. Just speculating here, but does such a function, tool, etc.. not exist because this type of case doesn't arise that often?

Comment: I'd guess that such a tool doesn't exist (if it doesn't exist) because there are too many potential definitions of "correct" output, which are all significantly different. Whereas scripting what you want is just some trigonometry/computational geography (at least, if the units are Cartesian).

Comment: I'll have to spend some time think about how (and perhaps 'if') I want to do that at the moment. Maybe a longer-term project.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [Regularize Building Footprint](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/regularize-building-footprint.htm) (3D Analyst) does exactly that. It will produce what you need or something very easy to edit (using perpendiculars and parallels):

[image]

UPDATE

There is a feature in above tool, that I don't like. It changes the shapes of polygons with perfectly orthogonal angles. So I decided to develop my own. Algorithm is simple:

- take longest segment (keep it in memory) and find projection of mid-point (MP) of the next segment on it. This creates point 1 for future polygon
- draw line from projected point to MP and beyond, find projection of next mid-point to create point 2, etc. until (N-1) projections found. N is no of segments.
- finally find projection on longest segment.

[image]

EXPERIMENT

I skewed 16 'perfect' building footprints by randomly changing coordinates of their vertices:

[image]

It is a decent noise for the size of polygons in question. Picture below shows output for one of 16 polygons:

[image]

Complete set [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rFzCcviNna8mgz5s0ATdY7eOOwDUJMue/view?usp=sharing).

I can post a script, but it is for ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: I must give this a test-drive ... thank you for pointing it out, FelixIP ...